# Android gradle build fails on ubuntu agents on ADO but compiles on Windows, macos

Tags: android, macos, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

For a few days now I've been scratching my head at this.

I have a azure-pipeline yaml build using a gradle task in java 11, it's running on a macos MS hosted agent and build perfectly, however for performance and cost reasons we want to switch to ubuntu agents. When switching the build fails with the following error :

```
> Task :app:compileStagingDebugKotlin FAILED
e: /home/vsts/work/1/s/app/src/main/java/org/xxx/xxxxx/profile/contactInfo/xxxxFragment.kt: (305, 59): Unresolved reference: xxxxxxFragmentMenu
```

xxxxFragmentmenu being a reference to a navigation menu (androidx.navigation) (sorry i'm not an android developer).

The thing is that it is working if i use a windows agent as well as a macos one. The only notable difference i can see between the MS hosted agent capabilities is that the jdk version on ubuntu is a little behind for the v11

- ubuntu : 11.0.14.1+1 (default)Eclipse Temurin    JAVA_HOME_11_X64
- macos & windows 2019 : 11.0.14+101   Eclipse Temurin     JAVA_HOME_11_X64

I've also created a vm on ubuntu 20.0.4, installed android studio and was able to successfully compile the variant AssembleStagingDebug.
This variant is indeed being compiled on Windows and MacOs, below an example of successful compilation with macos.

```
> Task :app:compileStagingDebugKotlin
w: Flag is not supported by this version of the compiler: -Xallow-jvm-ir-dependencies
w: ATTENTION!
This build uses unsafe internal compiler arguments:
w: /Users/runner/work/1/s/app/src/main/java/org/xxx/xxx/profile/documents/documentation/DocumentationViewModel.kt: (196, 25): Unchecked cast: Any? to List<TrustCategory>
w: /Users/runner/work/1/s/app/src/main/java/org/xxx/xxx/profile/documents/documentation/DocumentationViewModel.kt: (265, 25): Unchecked cast: Any? to List<TrustDocumentInfo>
w: /Users/runner/work/1/s/app/src/main/java/org/xxx/xxx/profile/documents/documentation/DocumentationViewModel.kt: (390, 25): Unchecked cast: Any? to List<TrustDocumentShared>
w: /Users/runner/work/1/s/app/src/main/java/org/xxx/xxx/profile/documents/proofOfIdentity/ProofOfIdentityViewModel.kt: (65, 25): Unchecked cast: Any? to List<TrustPvid>
w: /Users/runner/work/1/s/app/src/main/java/org/xxx/xxx/splash/FragmentSplash.kt: (67, 13): The expression is unused
w: /Users/runner/work/1/s/app/src/main/java/org/xxx/xxx/util/LocaleUtil.kt: (22, 19): 'updateConfiguration(Configuration!, DisplayMetrics!): Unit' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: /Users/runner/work/1/s/app/src/main/java/org/xxx/xxx/util/file/UriUtils.kt: (31, 34): Variable 'selection' initializer is redundant
w: /Users/runner/work/1/s/app/src/main/java/org/xxx/xxx/util/file/UriUtils.kt: (32, 45): Variable 'selectionArgs' initializer is redundant
w: /Users/runner/work/1/s/app/src/main/java/org/xxx/xxx/util/file/UriUtils.kt: (73, 60): 'getExternalStorageDirectory(): File!' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: /Users/runner/work/1/s/app/src/main/java/org/xxx/xxx/util/file/UriUtils.kt: (220, 36): 'getExternalStorageDirectory(): File!' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: /Users/runner/work/1/s/app/src/main/java/org/xxx/xxx/util/file/UriUtils.kt: (225, 20): Unsafe use of a nullable receiver of type String?
w: /Users/runner/work/1/s/app/src/main/java/org/xxx/xxx/util/file/UriUtils.kt: (229, 20): Unsafe use of a nullable receiver of type String?
w: /Users/runner/work/1/s/app/src/main/java/org/xxx/xxx/util/file/UriUtils.kt: (243, 17): Variable 'size' is never used
w: /Users/runner/work/1/s/app/src/main/java/org/xxx/xxx/util/file/UriUtils.kt: (258, 28): Variable 'read' initializer is redundant
w: /Users/runner/work/1/s/app/src/main/java/org/xxx/xxx/util/file/test/RealPathUtil.kt: (9, 24): 'CursorLoader' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: /Users/runner/work/1/s/app/src/main/java/org/xxx/xxx/util/file/test/RealPathUtil.kt: (31, 52): 'DATA: String' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: /Users/runner/work/1/s/app/src/main/java/org/xxx/xxx/util/file/test/RealPathUtil.kt: (34, 28): 'constructor CursorLoader(Context!, Uri!, Array<(out) String!>!, String!, Array<(out) String!>!, String!)' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: /Users/runner/work/1/s/app/src/main/java/org/xxx/xxx/util/file/test/RealPathUtil.kt: (34, 28): 'CursorLoader' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: /Users/runner/work/1/s/app/src/main/java/org/xxx/xxx/util/file/test/RealPathUtil.kt: (35, 35): 'loadInBackground(): Cursor!' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: /Users/runner/work/1/s/app/src/main/java/org/xxx/xxx/util/file/test/RealPathUtil.kt: (38, 84): 'DATA: String' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: /Users/runner/work/1/s/app/src/main/java/org/xxx/xxx/util/file/test/RealPathUtil.kt: (69, 40): 'getExternalStorageDirectory(): File!' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: /Users/runner/work/1/s/app/src/main/java/org/xxx/xxx/util/file/test/RealPathUtil.kt: (77, 44): 'getExternalStorageDirectory(): File!' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: /Users/runner/work/1/s/app/src/main/java/org/xxx/xxx/util/file/test/RealPathUtilExts.kt: (54, 73): 'DATA: String' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: /Users/runner/work/1/s/app/src/main/java/org/xxx/xxx/util/file/test/RealPathUtilExts.kt: (73, 71): Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expected
w: /Users/runner/work/1/s/app/src/main/java/org/xxx/xxx/util/file/test/URIPathHelper.kt: (27, 40): 'getExternalStorageDirectory(): File!' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

> Task :app:compileStagingDebugJavaWithJavac
```

To try to debug further and excluding the possibility that this was coming for the gradle task, i've also tried to compile through a bash script calling `./gradlew clean AssembleStagingDebug --scan` which works locally but not on the ubuntu agent.

The android sdk is installed and available, we are using the 30.0.3, everything else seems the same.

What can cause this? We really want to get on Ubuntu agents..  Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

I took a look at the generated files from the navigation graph xml file and in Azure DevOps ubuntu agent unlike when using macOs **one navigation action node is not being generated**...

I also tried to be the closest from the agent dev environment by using the same jdk and sdk as the ubuntu agent on Azure DevOps:
openjdk version "11.0.14.1" 2022-02-08
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-11.0.14.1+1 (build 11.0.14.1+1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-11.0.14.1+1 (build 11.0.14.1+1, mixed mode)
javac 11.0.14.1

But still couldn't reproduce the same behavior locally.

Anyone with an idea on how to approach this now?

**Edit 2:**

I found the problem, it was due to the issue of duplicated fragments (same ids) with different definitions. on Windows and Ubuntu, contrary to macOs it seems that the generated files are not processed in the same order resulting on overwitten files that doesn't contain some of the actions. We've made a temporary fix to include the same definitions for all fragments sharing the same IDs. Now it works on all platforms.

Comment: There's not much info to go on, but I can see `compileStaging` , are you sure the Mac & Windows builds are also attempting to build staging when they are "successful"? Have you tried spinning up a local Ubuntu machine to see if you can get it to work locally?

Comment: i've added more infos in the questions. Hope it helps.

Comment: hmm if its working on a local Ubuntu install then its a problem with the hosted ubuntu azure agent ( obviously :) ) . Usually these things are to do with build tools versions / accepting the tools T&C's / not pointing at the correct SDK / permissions issues. For your own sanity I'd say try creating a new agent from scratch and see where you get to :-) (for the record I've had ubuntu azure agents working in the past)

Comment: Hi, @Blundell, thanks for your answer. The problem is that we are using Microsoft hosted agents for the moment, not self-hosted. And if possible we would like to stay on it for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it was due to the issue of duplicated fragments (same ids) with different definitions. on Windows and Ubuntu, contrary to macOs it seems that the generated files are not processed in the same order resulting on overwitten files that doesn't contain some of the actions. We've made a temporary fix to include the same definitions for all fragments sharing the same IDs. Now it works on all platforms.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).